# Merge [gnumakefiles] with [gnu-make]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[gnumakefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnumakefiles) should be synonyms with [gnu-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-make)

[gnu-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-make) is already synonyms with [gmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmake) and [gnumakefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnumakefile)*(no 's')* and has over 900 questions tagged with it. [gnumakefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnumakefiles) currently has 53 questions associated with it. Many of which also have [gnu-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-make) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. There were only 39 questions with the former and *not* the latter anyway.